# Mypy doesn't typecheck function with Type[NamedTuple]

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy

I have a function that accepts a class that derives from `NamedTuple` and converts it into a schema. However when I run MyPy on the following code it fails with `Argument 1 to "to_schema" has incompatible type "Type[Foo]"; expected "Type[NamedTuple]"`

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Type


def to_schema(named_tuple: Type[NamedTuple]):
    pass

class Foo(NamedTuple):
    pass


to_schema(Foo)
```

Is there a way to properly type the code so that it typechecks with MyPy?

Edit:
Python documentation states that `Type[Foo]` accepts any subclasses of `Foo` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type). I have multiple subclasses of `NamedTuple`, for entities in our data model, so I'm looking for a way to annotate the function in a way that would typecheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root issue with your code is that `NamedTuple` is not an actual type -- it's actually just a special sort of "type constructor" that synthesizes an entirely new class and type. E.g. if you try printing out the value of `Foo.__mro__`, you'll see `(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'object'>)` -- `NamedTuple` is not present there at all.

That means that `NamedTuple` isn't actually a valid type to use at all -- in that regard, it's actually a little surprising to me that mypy just silently lets you construct `Type[NamedTuple]` to begin with.

To work around this, you have several potential approaches:

1. Rather then using `Type[NamedTuple]`, use either `Type[tuple]` or `Type[Tuple[Any]]`.

   Your `Foo` genuinely *is* a subtype of a tuple, after all.
2. If you need methods or fields that are specifically present only in namedtuples, use a custom protocol. For example, if you particularly need the `_asdict` method in namedtuples, you could do:

   ```
   from typing_extensions import Protocol

   class NamedTupleProto(Protocol):
       def _asdict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]: ...

   def to_schema(x: Type[NamedTupleProto]) -> None: pass

   class Foo(NamedTuple):
       pass

   to_schema(Foo)
   ```

   Note that you will need to install the `typing_extensions` third party library to use this, though there are plans to [formalize Protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) and add it to Python at some point. (I forget if the plan was Python 3.7 or 3.8).
3. Add a type ignore or a cast on the call to `to_schema` to silence mypy. This isn't the greatest solution, but is also the quickest.

For related discussion, see [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3915). Basically, there's consensus on the mypy team that somebody ought to do something about this NamedTuple thing, whether it's by adding an error message or by adding an officially sanctioned protocol, but I think people are too busy with other tasks/bugs to push this forward. (So if you're bored and looking for something to do...)

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed answer! I’m ignoring the typecheck for now, but I’ll definitely look into a better solution now — probably implementing my own protocol, since I need `_asdict`